# MongoDB "Or+And" query

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I started now with MongoDB. Now I've a small problem with the query:

```
        $finder = array(
            '$or'           => array(
                array('categoryId'            => $category),
                array('parentCategoryId'      => $category),
                array('topCategoryId'         => $category),
            ),
            'Title'      => array(
                array('$regex'        => $query),
            ),
        );
```

I want to get all entries with the category id "1" for example and the title-regex "blues".

Can anyone help?

Comment: So what's the problem? That should work for you.

Comment: But it didn't... Now I've got it :)